# Object property with extra functions in Python

Tags: python, caching, properties, descriptor

I am developing a descriptor basing myself in the ideas of `@property`. What I would like is to understand if there is any way of easily extending the behavior of property beyond setting/getting.

The concrete example: I am communicating with a device, and would like to have a property that can set/get/update. In this way, when I `set`, I pass the new value to the device, and store it in the cache. When I `get`, I retrieve the cached value. When I `update`, the device is re-asked for the value. In this way, can avoid unnecessary communication with the device, unless explicitly triggered.

I don't know if there is a pattern that I am missing that may be a straightforward solution. An option would be to invalidate the cache when using a special value in `set`, but I don't think it is a good idea to assume a specific value for triggering the update.

Comment: I mean, you'r `get` function would essentially contain that sort of logic. Here's an example: https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/7bdcd5db503f49c794709bbad6df3b5f0e344080/pyglet/shapes.py#L173-L184 which rely quite hevily on this. Your `set` could check if the value/key already exists and take action accordingly.

Comment: Does not look like what I am looking for. I don't see how they implement the update while getting, they are updating while setting. I'll extend my question.

Comment: Even if there is a way to extend the property function like you described, what would the syntax look like to make use of that additional functionality? Assume `a` is a property of class `A`, then `b = A.a` calls `a.getter` , while `A.a = b` calls `a.setter`. What syntax would you suggest that calls the '`updater`'?

Comment: That is what I am asking, is there a way? For example, ``del`` triggers a special method. Perhaps there is an ``upd``. Or perhaps descriptors are not the way to go and there is another approach I am not aware of. Or perhaps there is a way of knowing whether ``get`` is being accessed with an extra ``.update``?

Comment: @AquilesCarattino Well, the `get` is just a function, implement your logic. There's no automatic cache. I'm just saying that the getters and setters can support this, if you build it. If you're not interested in finding a solution within the current framework, then the boring answer is: No, you can't. If you're willing to play around with the getters and setters and implement a "hidden cache" in the background, that's fully duable. But there's no current syntax for it other than put in the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the difference between your `getter` and `updater`. If you want your `updater` to have its own syntax, you would need to define a new operator.

Comment: What would be the difference between an `update` to invalidate cache and a `foo.prop = None`? Your `get` would just return an object of your choice, i.e. the cache you're speaking of.  If you don't want that cache returned, you can `set` it to something else via the setter `foo.prop = ...`.  There's not much to go around it because the moment the syntax calls `foo.prop` you're directly dealing with the "cached" object itself, not the `property`.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand the difference between your `getter` and `updater`, but here is some sample code which implements a cache that stores previous variable values. Maybe this helps you to find what you are looking for.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a_cache = [1]

    @property  # <- this defines a.getter
    def a(self):
        return self._a_cache[-1]

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a_cache.append(value)

    def undo(self):
        if len(self._a_cache) > 1:
            self._a_cache.pop()
        else:
            print('No previous values')

    def update(self):
        # what is supposed to happen here as opposed to the getter?
        pass
        
        
var = A()
print(var.a)

var.a = 10
print(var.a)

var.undo()
print(var.a)

var.update()
# ?
```